# Prove that $\arctan v - \arctan u < v - u$ if $u<v$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The following is the last exercise of chapter 5 of the *Advanced Calculus* by Fitzpatrick:

> Prove that $\arctan v - \arctan u < v - u$ if $u<v$.

Suppose two sequences $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$. If the $$\dfrac{\arctan v_n - \arctan u_n}{v_n - u_n} <1 \quad \text{ for all indices } n, $$ But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It should be $<1$, once you divide by $v_n-u_n$, which is fine.

Comment: @carmichael561, I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\arctan v-\arctan u}{v-u}=\frac{1}{v-u}\int_{u}^{v}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}\color{red}{<}\frac{1}{v-u}\int_{u}^{v}dz=1\tag{1} $$
since the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ attains its absolute maximum, $1$, at a single point ($z=0$).

Answer (score 5):

Do the math more carefully: saying $\arctan v-\arctan u<v-u$ is the same as saying
$$
\frac{\arctan v-\arctan u}{v-u}<1
$$
The mean value theorem says
$$
\frac{\arctan v-\arctan u}{v-u}=\frac{1}{1+w^2}
$$
for some $w\in(u,v)$, so…

Comment: what about w=0?

Comment: @Edi That's the only case you need to worry about.

Comment: Must $\le$ be replaced with $<$ in $\arctan v - \arctan u < v - u$?